# TPL Dataflow ActionBlock that doesn't allow the same data to exist in the buffer

Tags: c#, .net, tpl-dataflow

I'm implementing a queue to update leaderboards when score data changes in the background.  Updating the leaderboard is a relatively expensive operation, so if we say "Update leaderboard 5" and then immediately say "Update leaderboard 5" again before the first one is finished, we should just update leaderboard 5 one time.

To do this I'm using TPL dataflow to create an `ActionBlock` which takes an id to update, then calls the `subscriptions` delegate which does the actual work.  I'm using a `BufferBlock` to post to, which checks a `HashSet` to see if the leaderboard is already pending update, and if so posts the data to the `ActionBlock`, otherwise posts it to a `NullTarget`.  When a leaderboard is updated, I remove the id from `dupeMap` so it can be processed again if data changes.

The goal is to *minimize* the duplicates, if there's a few edge cases where the same leaderboard might be updated twice, it's not a huge deal.  Here's my code, I'd appreciate any comments or feedback since I'm not a complete TPL-Dataflow master (this is the first time I've used anything besides `ActionBlock<T>`.

```
public class LeaderboardQueue : ILeaderboardQueue
{
    private Func<int, Task> subscriptions;
    private readonly ActionBlock<int> block;
    private readonly BufferBlock<int> filter;
    private readonly HashSet<int> dupeMap = new(); // Ensure the same leaderboard isn't being recalc'ed twice in the queue, which would be a waste of time

    public LeaderboardQueue()
    {
        block = new ActionBlock<int>(async activityId =>
            {
                dupeMap.Remove(activityId);
                await subscriptions(activityId);
            },
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 });
        
        filter = new BufferBlock<int>();
        filter.LinkTo(block, dupeMap.Add);
        filter.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<int>());
    }
    
    public async Task MarkLeaderboardDirty(int activityId)
    {
        await filter.SendAsync(activityId);
    }

    public void Subscribe(Func<int, Task> fnProcess)
    {
        subscriptions += fnProcess;
    }

    public async Task Shutdown()
    {
        filter.Complete();
        await filter.Completion;
        
        block.Complete();
        await block.Completion;
    }
}
```

I also have a question on the `Shutdown` method.  Am I correct to `Complete()` both blocks, or do I just need to complete one of them?  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you name a `BufferBlock` as `filter`? What does it filter?

Comment: Can you also please share with us a sample usage code?

Comment: *Am I correct to Complete() both blocks, or do I just need to complete one of them* Since they are linked it is enough to call `Complete` on the first block and `await` the `Completion` of the last block.

Comment: @PeterCsala I think the `filter` variable name came from [this example](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/20690) I had found online..  I think it makes sense, as it filters out duplicates.

Comment: @PeterCsala The `ILeaderboardQueue` instance is a Singleton used by other services, which call `.MarkLeaderboardDirty()` to add things to the queue.  I think that part is pretty straight forward.

Comment: I've played a little bit with your code. I've stated earlier that completion propagates automatically if they are linked. I was wrong that's not the default you have to set it in the `LinkTo` call: `new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }`

Comment: Because of the `dupeMap.Remove(activityId);` call your queue implementation has a race condition. If the processing of `activityId#1` completed sooner than the second call of `MarkLeaderboardDirty` with `activityId#1` then you process it twice. If the second call happened sooner than the processing then it won't be re-processed.

Comment: @PeterCsala Yea I guess I could move the `dupeMap.Remove()` call to after the `await subscriptions()` call happens.  There'd be more chance the same leaderboard is processed twice, but not a big deal.  The goal here is to minimize recalculating the same data twice as much as possible.

Comment: Okay. Otherwise it seems okay for me.